# How to refresh reinstantiate/refresh Pip Slider plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I am using http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/ slider plugin and having trouble in reinstantiating the plugin values. We have a checkbox, if it is checked the slider should show a range,if checkbox if unchecked, the max range should be set and user can set only the start range. and vice versa.

The code I am using is:

```html
if (true) 
{
        $this.find(".div").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 50,
            value: startMonth,
            range: "max"
        });
}
else
{
        $this.find(".div").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 50,
            values: [10, 20],
            range: true
        });
}
```

I  also tried updating options but it is behaving weird.

```html
$this.find(".div").slider()
.slider("option", "value", startMonth)
.slider("option", "values", null)
.slider("pips", "refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be your `null` which is causing the error. Also you shouldn't call: `.slider()` just before setting the options, that's only needed to create a *NEW* slider :)
.

**update:** changed settings slightly, works more consistent: https://jsfiddle.net/fbwsn4uc/2/

```
if( x ) {
  settings = {
    max: 30,
    range: "max",
    value: 10
  };
} else {
  settings = {
    min: 0,
    max: 30,
    range: true,
    values: [ 5, 20 ]
  };
}

// refresh the slider with the new settings.
$(".slider")
  .slider( "option", settings )
  .slider( "pips", "refresh" );
```

Comment: It does, but when you click on slider handle to change the value- it change the handle but range is not set.

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing is to destroy the slider and re-initializing it. I am not sure if that's an elegant way to do that, but it seems working fine.

```js
$this.find(".div").slider("destroy").removeClass("ui - slider - pips");

if (true)
  {
  this.find(".div").slider({
                min: 0,
                max: months.length - 1,
                value: startMonth,
                range: "max"
            })
            .slider("pips", {
                rest: "label",
                labels: months
            });
  }
else
  {
            this.find(".div").slider({
                min: 0,
                max: months.length - 1,
                values: [startMonth, months.length - 2],
                range: true
            })
             .slider("pips", {
                 rest: "label",
                 labels: months
             });

  }
```

Comment: this is not elegant, and probably bad for performance :( check my other response for a better way to refresh/rebuild the slider.